# Why pipe(take(1) doesn't complete the RxJS stream

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable

```
 async goToAuthorizePage(): Promise<void> {

    const loader: HTMLIonLoadingElement = await this.loadingService.presentLoader();

    this.pickUpParcelService.pickUpParcelChanged$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => {

     // code

      this.pickUpParcelService.setPickUpParcel(pickUpParcel); // This line again emit the value

      this.router.navigateByUrl('authorize-and-sign');

    }, () => this.loadingService.dismissLoader(loader)); // never end or fire
  }
```

pick-up-parcel.service.ts

```
    private pickUpParcelSubject$: BehaviorSubject<Partial<PickUpParcelModel>> = 
new BehaviorSubject<Partial<PickUpParcelModel>>(null);

     pickUpParcelChanged$: Observable<Partial<PickUpParcelModel>> = 
this.pickUpParcelSubject$.asObservable();
    
    
      constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }
    
      setPickUpParcel(pickUpParcel: Partial<PickUpParcelModel>): void {
        this.pickUpParcelSubject$.next(pickUpParcel);
      }
```

With my code above where I cannot close the loader. I can do that if I'll put that within the subscription. But then I need to repeat it again on error use case too. That is why I would like to put it in a single place like a completion event (i.e. DRY principal). Even though I have used `pipe(take(1)` why it doesn't complete? Do I have a better approach to follow here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one as third function is of complete one

```
 async goToAuthorizePage(): Promise<void> {
    
        const loader: HTMLIonLoadingElement = await this.loadingService.presentLoader();
    
        this.pickUpParcelService.pickUpParcelChanged$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => { 
// 1st block
    
         // your code
    
        }, (errorBlock) => {} , 2nd block
       (completeblock) => this.loadingService.dismissLoader(loader));  3rd block
      }
```

or you can try **finalize** rxjs operator in pipe

```
        this.pickUpParcelService.pickUpParcelChanged$.pipe(take(1) , finalize(() => this.loadingService.dismissLoader(loader))).subscribe(res => { 
// your code 
})
```